# Critical Point of $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ I can find critical points by finding the $1\times 2$ Jacobian matrix, setting each partial derivative equal to zero and solving the equations. I can then classify them by finding the $2\times 2$ Hessian matrix and calculating the eigenvalues.

But now suppose I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, say, $f(x, y) = (y \cos(x), y \sin(x))$. How would I then find and classify critical points?

Which partial derivatives do I calculate and set to zero? Would my Jacobian matrix now be a $2\times 2$ matrix? And if so then what would the Hessian matrix be like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k$ a differentiable function, then the differential at $p$ is the linear map ${\rm d}f_p: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k$ such that $$f(p+h)=f(p)+{\rm d}f_p(h) + r(h),$$ with $r(h)/\|h\| \to 0$ as $h \to 0$. We say that $p$ is a critical point of $f$ if ${\rm d}f_p$ is not surjective. Since ${\rm d}f_p$ is a linear map, we can consider its matrix in the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^k$. It will be a $k \times n$ matrix - the Jacobian matrix. You take *all* the partial derivatives, set them to zero, and solve. $$Jf(p) = [{\rm d}f_p]_{\mathsf{can},\mathsf{can}} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\end{bmatrix}_{1 \leq i \leq k, \, 1 \leq j \leq n}$$

Note also that for $k = 1$, we have $Jf(p) = \nabla f(p)$.

The Hessian, as far as I know, it is only good for maps $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$. In $\Bbb R^n$, $n > 1$, we don't have an order relation $\leq$, so we can't talk about "minimum" or "maximum" points.

However, you can consider the map $$\begin{align}{\rm d}f:& \Bbb R^n \to L(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^k) \\ p &\mapsto {\rm d}f_p \in L(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^k) \end{align}$$ and ask yourself if this one is differentiable itself. Then you can start thinking of second derivatives and such, and you can identify ${\rm d}^2f_p$ with a bilinear form $B(\cdot, p)$, or something like this, which I think that would be the closest you get to a Hessian.

But I digress. In your example $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ is given by $(y\cos x, y \sin x)$. So $$Jf(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}-y \sin x & \cos x \\ y \cos x & \sin x  \end{bmatrix}$$ Since $$2 = \dim \ker {\rm d}f_p + \dim {\rm Im}\,{\rm d}f_p,$$ our chances are that $\dim {\rm Im}\,{\rm d}f_p = 0$ or $1$. It can't be zero because $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ can't be zero at the same time. Every point $(x,0)$ will be a critical point because the first column will be zero. Then you would have to check if there are values $(x,y)$ such that the two columns are multiples - this does not happen because the columns are orthogonal vectors.

---

Thanks to PVAL and zhw for pointing corrections and for the useful comments.

Comment: "The function has no critical points, since cosx and sinx can't be zero at the same time." No. The function has no points where the derivative vanishes. A point  $p$ is a critical point if $df_p$ is not surjective. So in this case $y=0$ would be a whole line of critical points (and there would be at least a couple more than that as well).

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of functions taking values on $\Bbb R$. I'll fix it

Comment: @PVAL I see no other critical points other than the ones on the $x$-axis. Note that the column vectors are orthogonal, so they are independent if they are nonzero.

Comment: I fixed the answer, and I think everything is ok now. Thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: _Then you would have to check if there are values (x,y) such that the two columns are multiples - it seems that there aren't any._ True, just because the determinant of that Jacobi matrix equals $y$ and only zero $y$ makes it zero.

Comment: So am I right in saying that to find the critical points in this case I work out what the Jacobian is and look at what values of $x$ and $y$ make the two columns linearly dependant?

Comment: In the $2 \times 2$ case, yes.

Comment: For the higher dimensional cases would I need to find values of variables that make all of the columns linearly dependent or would it suffice to find values so that some of them are?

Comment: Just for some of them. Separate the analysis by dimensions, like I did: rank 0, then rank 1, etc.